# Different accelerometer values across multiple devices

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm making a game which uses the device's accelerometer to fill a progress bar.
On my Note 2 it takes me about 20 seconds shaking the phone up and down to fill the bar, however I tried on a ZTE Blade and it took me 4 seconds.

Is there any way to calibrate the accelerometers within my code? This is what I'm doing:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        if (!mInitialized) {
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            mInitialized = true;
        } else {
            float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
            float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);
            if (deltaX < NOISE) deltaX = (float)0.0;
            if (deltaY < NOISE) deltaY = (float)0.0;
            if (deltaZ < NOISE) deltaZ = (float)0.0;
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;

            if(deltaY == 0){
                return;
            }

            sProgress += deltaY;
            pb.setProgress(sProgress);


        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue may be with frequency of Accelerometer.Dont use below android constants while registering.

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

these valuse are different for different device.

```
int SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST    get sensor data as fast as possible
int SENSOR_DELAY_GAME   rate suitable for games
int SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL rate (default) suitable for screen orientation changes
int SENSOR_DELAY_UI rate suitable for the user interface
```

Use Hard coded values in microseconds like for frequency 1 Hz

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,1000000);
```

Hope it solves.

Comment: what behaviour you are getting now ?

Comment: Approximately the same as before, in my phone it took 10 seconds and in the other 3.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to making the frequency equal is something like the following solution.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
  if(sensorEventTooQuick(sensorEvent.timestamp)) {
    return;
  }

  mLastSensorEventTime = sensorEvent.timestamp;

  // process sensor
}

private boolean sensorEventTooQuick(long sensorTime) {
  long diff = sensorTime - mLastSensorEventTime;
  return diff < MINIMUM_SENSOR_EVENT_GAP;
}
```

Things to consider:

- You want to make sure you choose MINIMUM_SENSOR_EVENT_GAP to be small enough as to not lose information. The accelerometer is very quick so this is usually not a problem, but could be an issue for other sensors depending on the application.
- Make sure to test different values across different devices.

I do this since it guarantees that you will not receive events faster than your limit.